# Pandas- Read CSV file two lines, qoutes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read the following csv file format to a pandas DataFrame

```
"Indikator";"Grupp";"2014M04";"2014M05";"2014M06";"2014M07";"2014M08";"2014M09";"2014M10";"2014M11";"2014M12";"2015M01";"2015M02";"2015M03";"2015M04";"2015M05";"2015M06";"2015M07";"2015M08";"2015M09";"2015M10";"2015M11";"2015M12";"2016M01"

"Konfidensindikatorhushåll(CCI)";"Alla";100.3;102.1;101.8;100.4;95.7;102.0;97.8;98.3;98.4;98.8;97.5;100.7;97.2;99.1;98.0;96.4;99.8;98.2;98.9;96.2;98.6;97.5
```

The first row is dates and the second row is the values. Any suggestions how i can procced to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are your expecting output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use usual `pd.read_csv` with `header=None` and then transpose your dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file', sep=';', header=None)

In [31]: df.T
Out[31]: 
            0                               1
0   Indikator  Konfidensindikatorhushåll(CCI)
1       Grupp                            Alla
2     2014M04                           100.3
3     2014M05                           102.1
4     2014M06                           101.8
5     2014M07                           100.4
6     2014M08                            95.7
7     2014M09                           102.0
8     2014M10                            97.8
9     2014M11                            98.3
10    2014M12                            98.4
11    2015M01                            98.8
12    2015M02                            97.5
13    2015M03                           100.7
14    2015M04                            97.2
15    2015M05                            99.1
16    2015M06                            98.0
17    2015M07                            96.4
18    2015M08                            99.8
19    2015M09                            98.2
20    2015M10                            98.9
21    2015M11                            96.2
22    2015M12                            98.6
23    2016M01                            97.5
```

Comment: Thank you. This enabled me to display the data. I have another problem. Pandas do not seem to recognize that the column 1 are values. I would like to plot this data in a graph with the dates on the x axis and values on the Y axis. Any suggestions how i can proceed? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Martin598 you need to convert it to numeric or float. You could do it with `astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric(errors='coerce')` for you column 1

Comment: Thank you very much Anton! Works perfectly